# Why does a list of generators only return the elements of the last generator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, generator

I'm given an arbitrary list of objects (e.g. `['foo', 'bar']`). My goal is to produce a list of equal size where every element in the result list is a generator that repeats the respective input element 5 times.

This is a big simplification of what I actually want to do, and I am aware that there are many ways in which to solve this task.
However, I have stumbled upon some weird behavior in how I wanted to solve this that I can not explain.

Here is my solution to the above task:

```py
my_iterators = [
    (element for _ in range(5))
    for element in ["foo", "bar"]
]
for my_iterator in my_iterators:
    print(list(my_iterator))
```

I now expected the output to be:

```
['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo']
['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar']
```

However, to my surprise it was instead:

```
['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar']
['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar']
```

Why is it that `(element for _ in range(5))` seems to be an iterator over the last element in the input_list irregarding of what it actually is in the context of `for element in ["foo", "bar"]`?
How would I need to adapt my code to produce what my original goal was?

Comment: I noticed that if I change `my_iterators` to `((element for _ in range(5)) for element in ["foo", "bar"])`, it actually produces the output I expected, but with `list((element for _ in range(5)) for element in ["foo", "bar"])` it again produces the one I cannot explain.

Comment: Research *late binding*.

Comment: Here is an easier way to define your iterator `my_iterators = [[i]*5 for i in ['foo', 'bar']]`

Comment: This is fundamentally the same problem that occurs in the tkinter duplicate I linked, the result of late binding.

Comment: I found a better duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by jonsharpe and David Buck in the comments, what's actually causing the non-intuitive behavior here is [Python's late binding](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures).

There seem to be multiple ways of fixing the posted code, one would be:

```py
def make_iterator(element):
    return (element for _ in range(5))

my_iterators = [
    make_iterator(element)
    for element in ["foo", "bar"]
]
for my_iterator in my_iterators:
    print(list(my_iterator))
```